# Breadcrumbs that follow navigation menu structure

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, breadcrumbs

Is it posible to create a breadcrumbs function for wordpress that will follow the menu structure and not the parent-child relationship?

I am customizing a PressEvent theme which has several custom posts types, speakers, organizing committee, etc. With shortcodes it is possible to add listing of any custom posts to a static page, but once you are on a single post the breadcrumbs are not including this static page on which posts are showing up, but the page with all of the custom posts.

Here is an example:

This is the trail when you are on a page that has organizing committee custom post types included (Organizing committee is the page title)

Home > About > Organizing committee

Once I click on a post the trail is like this (Here, organizing committee is link to a all custom posts and not the page from the bradcrumbs above):

Home > Organizing committee > Name and surname

There are some limitations of the theme, or I didn't find the solutions, but I can't add categories for custom posts types I create in order to add the category to the menu, and if in properties of each custom posts type I set it to appear in the main menu, I can't control its position in the navigation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's very simple: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109488/5986

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone has a similar issue, I found that [Breadcrumb NavXT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/installation/) plugin is getting the job done. You can select root page for each custom posts type you have in the theme.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote a plugin that just does this!

- Breadcrumbs based on WP Nav Menu
- Includes Rich Snippets (Microdata)
- Three different style
- Custom CSS editor
- Various settings
- Multilanguage ready, just English for now

You can find it at:
http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-nav-menu-breadcrumbs/4706192